# use swift on linux ，Persmission denied

Tags: linux, swift

[image]

using "swift" or "swiftc" ,Persmission denied 
using "sudo swiftc "    ，command not found

here is the path config

[image]

Comment: Instead of embedding images in your post (costly on bandwidth and IT carbon footprint), it would have been better to paste the text in the question, with proper formatting.

Comment: Just a guess: it looks like the tar.gz was unarchived using sudo. You should follow the install steps exactly as described on Swift.org (with normal user rights, not admin).

Comment: Please post actual code instead of screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`PATH` is only set for your `cocoa` user not for `root`.
Use

```
sudo -i set PATH
```

and run `swiftc` again. Alternative: run

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/swift/swift-2.3-SNAPSHOT-2016-01-06-a-ubuntu15.10
```

and run swift again